# Matlab memory problems

Tags: matlab, memory-leaks

I have a memory issue with a simple Matlab code I am running. When I run the following loop with the function listed, Matlab can go up to image 50 and after that it runs out of memory and ends. I need to run about 400 images and save them as a file on my hard drive for inspection. As you see in the function I am trying to clear everything but the memory still continues to grow. I have tried this Code with Matlab 13a and Matlab 14a and I have the same problem.
Here is the function (image is a  jp2 image)

```
 function plot1(image,boundary)
 image1=imread(image)
 h=figure
 imshow(image1)
 rectangle('Position',boundary)
 saveas(h,[image '_newimage.jpg'],'jpg)
 clear image1;clear h;cla reset;clear classes;
 clear all;close all;
 end
```

The above function is simple enough and I do not understand why the memory keeps increasing since I have cleared everything.
The program that calls this function looks like this (the image list and the xmin,xmax,width,height have been read from a list before in the program in a different loop):

```
for k=1:nf
     boundary=[xmin(k) ymin(k) width(k) height(k)]
     plot1(image{k},boundary)
end
```

Does anyone have any ideas about what is causing the memory increase?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: You might want to change your code to directly edit the image-array and use `imwrite` instead of saving a figure. No idea why it runs out of memory though. I don't think the code you show here is the problem. Clearing at the end of a function should not be necessary.

Comment: What is your release ans OS ?

Comment: I don't see a problem with the code either.  It could be other things related to your code before calling this function that may attribute to the error.  Can you show us the context of where you're calling this code?  What I mean to say is can you show us more of what's going on, other than your `for` loop?

Comment: I have tried it with Matlab 2013a and Matlab2014a on a Linux computer that runs Red Hat 6.3

Comment: rayryeng:i can give you more of the code but watching the memory it does not start to fill up until I start the for loop shown above. Before that the memory is at 0.5% so there is no problem before that.

Comment: There is a function called `whos` that can be used to see workspace variables in matlab and the size of them. I recommend that you do a function call to `whos` somewhere in the loop and set a breakpoint right after to inspect the memory consumption. If something there seems weird I guess the problem is found then. Otherwise I guess it might be MATLAB related. There is also functions that can monitor Java memory. Normally, when the java memory is getting full matlab starts to run really slow. The matlab gui becomes slow as well and may stop responding mouse events and so on.

Comment: @user2769660 - How large are these images?

Comment: @rayryeng: about 1GB each

Comment: @user2769660 - Uh... yeah....maybe that's why you're running out of memory lol.

Comment: @rayryeng. I understand that the images are too large, what I do not understand is why everytime the function closes, all the 'clear' commands do not free up the memory so the program can start like the first time when there was a lot of available memory

Comment: @patrik I tried to run this command clear java; java.lang
.System.gc(); to clear the java but there was no difference. Thank you for the suggestion though.

Comment: @user2769660 - That's very interesting... I'm not sure why.  Especially since you're doing `clear`.

Comment: @user2769660 Did you also try to monitor the memory or do that while using the debugger? That was the most important part of the comment. You wonder why you get this error. This means that you must do some research on it. We cannot do this, since we cannot reproduce your error. This has to do with not having your images, not your full code, not your computer, ... As you say it is weird, but unless we can reproduce the example it is not possible to solve (especially) weird things. If you set breakpoints and print "whos" information, you will learn what takes up memory.

Comment: If all images have the same size, you can try to preallocate a large global matrix and use it to load the images, this might be useful. Also try to call `pack` function every 10-20 images you process, it might help to free some memory.

Comment: Have you tried not producing a figure an using `imwrite` instead? 1GB images... Doing printouts of google maps?